# Custom Function in Django class based view not being overriden

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-inheritance

I have a parent View, and a child View. I want to override one custom function in the child view like so:

My URLs:

```py
path('<int:place_id>/add_images/', AddImages.as_view(), name="add-images"),
path('<int:place_id>/edit/images/', EditImages.as_view(), name="edit-images"),
```

```py
# PARENT:
class AddImages(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = images/add_images.html

    # HERE I GET THE CURRENT URL:
    def next_url(self):
        next_url = "?next={0}".format(self.request.path)
        print("NEXT URL:" + str(next_url))
        return next_url

    # AND I USE IT HERE:
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        # ...
        next_url = self.next_url()
        data = {'next_url' : next_url }
        return JsonResponse(data)


# CHILD:
class EditImages(AddImages):
    """
    Inherits from ImagesView. overwrites template and next_url

    """
    template_name = "images/edit_images.html"

    def next_url(self):
        next_url = "?next={0}".format(self.request.path)
        print("CHILD URL2:" + str(next_url))
        return next_url
```

I want to override the parent views next_url and pass it on to post()

currently the output only prints: "NEXT URL: ..."

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you double check that your URL configuration points to the correct View? Because the code looks fine, so I think there might be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: @malberts I have edited my answer and included the urls

Comment: To help debugging: copy the code in your parent class to the child class and do not extend the parent class. Then print out a different message. I just want to confirm that it is actually loading the class correctly.

Comment: I think it does since the template_name = ... does indeed load another template @malberts

Comment: I've got one more thing to try. Look in your templates if they are POSTing to the correct action. I think `edit_images.html` might accidentally be submitting to the add view.

Comment: @malberts thats it: <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
           style="display: none;"
           data-url="{% url 'add-images' parent_place.pk %}"
           data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

data-url should be edit-images instead of add-images! THANK YOU. can you it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views code is correct.

Your `edit_images.html` template most likely POSTs to the `AddImages` view, which makes it appear as if the `EditImages` view's overridden function is not called. Meanwhile it is just because the wrong view is triggered.